# Fetching data from Firebase - completion handler?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I need to fetch the data from Firebase database and my function is represented by two loops (one inside another). 
The code looks like this:

```
// THE 1ST LOOP FETCHING THE LIST OF EQUIPMENT
self.db.collection("fl_content")
            .whereField("_fl_meta_.schema", isEqualTo: "equipment")
            .whereField("active", isEqualTo: true)
            .getDocuments() {
                (querySnapshot, err) in

                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                } else {
                    var imagesToFetch: [String : String] = [:]

                    for equipmentDocument in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        if
                            let name = equipmentDocument.data()["name"] as? String, let images = equipmentDocument.data()["image"] as? [DocumentReference], let active = equipmentDocument.data()["default"] as? Bool, let def = equipmentDocument.data()["default"] as? Bool {
                            var documentData: [String: Any] = [:]
                            documentData["name"] = name
                            documentData["active"] = active
                            documentData["default"] = def
                            documentData["image"] = images[0].documentID
                            equipmentData[equipmentDocument.documentID] = documentData
                            if images.indices.contains(0) {

                                if FileManager.fileExists(path: "\(Constants.fileSavePath)\(images[0].documentID)") {
                                    self.toolList.append(
                                        Equipment(
                                            fbid: equipmentDocument.documentID,
                                            name: name,
                                            image: (documentData["image"] != nil) ? FileManager.fileToUIImage(path: images[0].documentID) : nil,
                                            active: active,
                                            def: def)
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    imagesToFetch[equipmentDocument.documentID] = images[0].documentID
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            print("No 'name' or 'image' found for this journey")
                        }
                    }
                    // got all data, let's get file paths and check if files exist
                    if(!imagesToFetch.isEmpty) {
                        // fetching paths to the images
                        self.db.collection("fl_files").whereField("_fl_meta_.docId", in: Array(imagesToFetch.values)).getDocuments() { 
                            (querySnapshot, err) in
                            if let err = err {
                               print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                            } else {
                               for imageDocument in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                 // Getting file paths from Firebase .....
                                 **HERE COMES THE 2ND LOOP FETCHING THE IMAGES FOR EACH GEAR**
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to form an array and pass this array (when all requests are done and data is fetched) to the next View. But I don't know how to tell if ALL Firebase requests have been processed.

If I place my code after those 2 loop, it might be executed before all the data is fetched, right? Some requests might still be in progress

**So how can I guaranteed that my array with the data is ready?**

When this sort of data is used for UI updates I don't really care is all is done as UI is subscribed to my "published" variables, but in this case **i wanna be able to detect when ALL REQUESTS are finished and data is fetched.**

What's the best way of doing this? Should i use the counter to check that all requests are completed and use completion handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DispatchGroup`. Use `enter()` and `leave()` functions to decide when a new task will start and did finish. Then, use `notify()` function to do whatever you need to do when the dispatch group is empty (which is decided by counting enter and leave actions).